# 1.8v to 3.3v level shifter logic family

Tags: digital-logic, level-shifting, buffer

I have been looking for a level shifter capable of doing 1.8v to 3.3v. For whatever reason it seems almost everyone carries **2v** to 3.3v shifter but 1.8v to 3.3v are few and far between. For practical reasons it should be at least 4 bit, preferably 8 bit. There are single-bit converters like that but it gets a bit daft doing 5 bits that way..

Can anyone recommend a logic family to use?
Some examples I've gone through so far:
74LVC8T245 (texas)
<strike>74AVC8T245 (nexperia)</strike>
74LVT244 (nexperia)
74LVT244 (texas)
<strike>74AVCH4T245 (Nexperia)</strike>
<strike>74AVCH4T245 (Texas)</strike>

I've actually found **one** chip that's good - Onsemi 74VHCT125, works from 2V to 5.5V and valid input high level starts at 1.2V. Now if only I could find a second source.. NXP, Toshiba and STM VHCT logic don't like 3.3V VCC. Texas has SN74LV4T125 which is valid but costs 3x more, Nexperia LVT125 doesn't do 1.8v.

Am I overlooking a logic family here, both of these look like corner cases that don't really fit either logic family, with other manufacturers having same families with different specs..

**update**
After sleeping on it I realized the chips featuring 4 or 8 (e.g. AVC4T245) actually have separate power for either side. I was just looking at the datasheet "3.3V min 2V logic high" line without realizing the VCC on the input side is 1.8V.

An omitted detail from my description was that there's a reasonably fast serial bus with flow control (2+2 lines) and a bunch of mostly static control signals. For the latter a simple PNP level shifter is perfectly fine.

Comment: Please list the logic spec you are trying to interface to.

Comment: TI SN74LV4T125 costs 0.66 in quantity 100. Are you saying you can't afford that?
Alternatively you could use a N-Channel MOSFET to do level shifting for a lower price.

Comment: Define slew rate and V in/out specs and tolerances and budget/qty

Comment: Along with load pF specs

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 thought the Vin/Vout was kind of obvious from the OP? 1.8v in, 3.3v out. Interfacing a cellular module and a 3.3V microcontroller (Synergy) as it happens. pF is normal logic and whatever trace capacitance, let's call it 20pF or less. Speed is pretty modest, the interface won't go above 3MHz, which by itself is not nothing, it'd take about 680R pull-up to achieve 10% rise time for open collector.

Comment: @EE_socal $0.35 if you buy a 2k reel from Texas, this kind of thing adds up quickly and there's the problem that someone somewhere is going to replace it with "identical" 2nd source and it stops working reliably. Any 74VHCT125 is going to be cross-compatible, right? Hence asking about the logic families. N-MOS will not (usually) work for 1.8v logic, but a humble NPN transistor would. Let's see, complementary biased NPN/PNP pair, around 4p, bc847, around 2p, times five signals, around 30p, so saving nothing and using more board area likely.

Comment: TI searches: [unidirectional](http://www.ti.com/logic-circuit/voltage-level-translation/unidirectional-voltage-translation/products.html#p848=4;6&p1524min=0.6;1.8&p1498=Catalog&sort=p1130;asc), [direction controlled](http://www.ti.com/logic-circuit/voltage-level-translation/direction-controlled-voltage-translation/products.html#p848=4;8&p1524min=0.455;1.8&p174max=3.3;5.5&p1498=Catalog&sort=p1130;asc)

Comment: @CL Yes, easy if you know already what you need. Bi-directional with direction control, dual supply and tristate combines about everything into one. I was expecting to find something like the 74HCT245-chip on the more recent logic families (VHCT/AHCT) that would accept 3.3V VCC but the only one like that is the LVT that doesn't like <2V input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having slept on this I made a spreadsheet of the various choices I had gone over last night. It seems I overlooked the circuits that have two voltage inputs - The datasheet **does** say that 3.3V would require 2+ volts for logic high, **but** you would have 1.8V on one side and 3.3V on the other so there's no problem.

So in this case e.g. AVC4T245 or AVCH4T would get the job done. It's 4-bit, split into two sections so I can use a single chip to handle the serial bus and use NPN/PNP dual transistors to do a simple open collector level shifter for the control signals. I could of course use the level shifter chip to do the mostly static control signals but it'd be a major overkill for the need.

The key is that "4" or "8" in the part name, e.g. LVC245 wouldn't work, LVC4245 does.

Those are not the cheapest logic around (~30p for 1k) but Nexperia and Texas have drop in replacements for various packages and there are no avc(h)4t245 chips that are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The LSF0204 will translate 1.8 to 3.3V. It requires a stiff pull-up on the high side if you care about switching speed.

The TXB0104 includes speed-up logic to improve risetime without the need for pull-up. It too can translate up from 1.8V.

Note that both these devices are bidirectional and transparent, making them flexible and easy to integrate.

Comment: That would get the job done but it's pricey and I'm not sure it'd have 2nd sources. See my update/answer, I mis-read the datasheet for dual power logic.

Comment: On Semi, Maxim, IDT, NXP make similar transmission-gate parts. Some are direct second sources for each other. On makes a direct cross for the TXB0104 for example. They’re popular for level-shifting bidirectional buses like I2C, SD Card/MMC and so forth.

Comment: You can also use a FET like the BSS138 to do this, as long as you’re mindful of the FET body diode.